# How to add an Object to an ArrayList?

Tags: android, object, arraylist, containers

i am trying to read from an SQLite-db, put the results into an Object of the custom-type Container, put the content of the Container into an ArrayList that i can build a listview filled by the arraylist. 
I am stuck at the point where i try to pass the filled Container-object to the ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Container> myListContent = new ArrayList<Container>();
{ 
Container conSelected = db.readContainer(i);

int s1 = conSelected.getId();
Log.i("LISTE", "id = " + s1);

String s2 = conSelected.getVorname();
Log.i("LISTE", "vorname = " + s2);

String s3 = conSelected.getName();
Log.i("LISTE", "name = " + s3);

// Container to the ArrayList  
//THIS NEXT COMMAND IS TROUBLING ME. ALL THREE GIVE THE SAME LOG
//myListContent.add(conSelected);
//myListContent.add(new Container(conSelected.getId(), conSelected.getVorname(), conSelected.getName()));
//myListContent.add(new Container(conSelected));

Log.i("LISTE", "line = " + myListContent); 
}

//this.myAdapter = new ListActivity(this, R.layout.row, myListContent);
```

my Logcat says:

```
03-11 18:17:43.336: I/LISTE(7477): id = 1
03-11 18:17:43.336: I/LISTE(7477): vorname = Fred
03-11 18:17:43.336: I/LISTE(7477): name = Einsner
03-11 18:17:43.336: I/LISTE(7477): line = [null]
...
03-11 18:17:43.375: I/LISTE(7477): id = 6
03-11 18:17:43.375: I/LISTE(7477): vorname = Wolf
03-11 18:17:43.375: I/LISTE(7477): name = Sechsland
03-11 18:17:43.375: I/LISTE(7477): line = [null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

can anyone help me with this? i am still a rookie :(

Comment: Can you show the definition of myListContent

Comment: Post the code code for your `new Container(conSelected)` constructor.

Comment: i just have one constructor in my Container.java:                  public Container(int parseInt, String vor, String nach) {
    this.id = parseInt;   
    this.vorname = vor;
    this.nachname = nach;
 }

Comment: That should work fine, please post the code where you print your list to logcat. It's possible what you're logging is incorrect.

Comment: Please click [edit] then paste this code into your question along with the code for your `readContainer()` method so we can see what is happening.

Comment: You are using `new Container(conSelected)` have you overridden this constructor? It sounds like you forgot and are using some super class' constructor...

Comment: i tried any of those three commands, but they all don't work. so maybe its really just some mistake from me, using the Log-command the wrong way..

Comment: What's this line `this.myAdapter = new ListActivity(this, R.layout.row, myListContent);` supposed to do? It makes no sense in the context of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @bofredo : u have `ArrayList<Container> myListContent = new ArrayList<Container>();` line inside any loop?

Comment: this AdapterCommand was just to show what my next step would be, but its not really connected to my question :)

Comment: @Sam : i think this line `ArrayList<Container> myListContent = new ArrayList<Container>();` is inside loop and making latest result as null ?

Comment: no it is not, i have edited my code meanhwile to show that

Comment: Please post `readContainer()` and `Container#toString()` in your question, otherwise it might be impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the answer has been choosen, I figured out what was the mistake and would like to let it here.

If you take a look at [Log.i](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#i%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29/), the method takes as parameters (String, String), since he's passing this line `Log.i("LISTE", "line = " + myListContent);`

myListContent suffers a String cast, which results in a null value. Differently from a `System.out.println(myListContent)"` which would pass the value of `Content.ToString()`

Comment: thx yes. i figured that after some people poked me in that direction. The problem was that the log stacking the "nulls" confused me!

Comment: I noticed that you went to the right conclusion, but the correct answer didn't point that, which may cause some misunderstanding for anyone who could read it later.

Comment: true. switching answer now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    ArrayList<Container> myListContent = new ArrayList<Container>();

   { 
    Container conSelected = db.readContainer(i);
    // Container to the ArrayList  
    myListContent.add(conSelected);

    Log.i("LISTE", "line = " + myListContent); 
    }
```

Comment: that was my first guess too, but the logcat got the same output there: line = {null,null,null}

Comment: i found it out myself as you poked my nose in the right direction. The Logging was the problem. you cant just simply let an Object-array beeing logcatted. so i used a StringBuilder to convert it into a String.
So your solution is right! :)